# How do I calculate a percentage in the row below subtotals on my Gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I would like to create a further row on my `GridView` or they could be stand alone cells that display the percentage change between `December2014DailySales` and `December2013DailySales` subtotals. I have provided the code behind. How would I do this?

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

        namespace TowelsRusV3
        {
            public partial class Sales_Comparison : System.Web.UI.Page
            {
                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }
                private decimal December2014DailySales = (decimal)0.0;
                private decimal December2013DailySales = (decimal)0.0;
                private decimal DailySalesDifference = (decimal)0.0;
                private decimal December2014DailyOrderCount = (decimal)0.0;
                private decimal December2013DailyOrderCount = (decimal)0.0;
                private decimal DailyOrderCountDifference = (decimal)0.0;
                protected void salecompgridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        December2014DailySales += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2014DailySales"));
                        December2013DailySales += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2013DailySales"));
                        DailySalesDifference += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DailySalesDifference"));
                        December2014DailyOrderCount += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2014DailyOrderCount"));
                        December2013DailyOrderCount += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2013DailyOrderCount"));
                        DailyOrderCountDifference += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DailyOrderCountDifference"));

                    }

                    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = String.Format("{0:c}", December2014DailySales);
                        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = String.Format("{0:c}", December2013DailySales);
                        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = String.Format("{0:c}", DailySalesDifference);
                        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = String.Format("{0:g}", December2014DailyOrderCount);
                        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = String.Format("{0:g}", December2013DailyOrderCount);
                        e.Row.Cells[6].Text = String.Format("{0:g}", DailyOrderCountDifference);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the problem. You just want to display `December2014DailySales / December2013DailySales` in a cell? PS: Instead of `(decimal)0.0`, just type `0.0M`, or `0M`, or `0`!

Comment: I want to display this calculation in a cell. December2014DailySales - December2013DailySales / December2014DailySales * 100 (This should show the percentage increase in sales from 2013 to 2014

Comment: And what is the problem then? Why can't you assign that to a cell? However, you should divide by `December2013DailySales` and use parenthesis. :)

Comment: The problem is i don;t know how to code it to display in a cell.

Comment: Haven't you debugged what you get in `gridview.Rows[0]` (for example) to find a cell data and then tried to assign something to it?

Comment: I am really new to .net so am not fully up to speed with how to do things.

Comment: Well, you can't learn all .NET from a question here, you should look for a tutorial and practice a lot. Meanwhile, this should store the value you want in the first cell of the gridview: `salecompgridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = (December2014DailySales - December2013DailySales) / December2013DailySales * 100;`.

Comment: So nearly there! I am getting a "cannot implicitly convert type decimal to string" error. Any idea's?

Comment: It's simple: `salecompgridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = ((December2014DailySales - December2013DailySales) / December2013DailySales * 100).ToString();`. If you need a specific format, use `.ToString("0.00");`, for example. More info about formatting here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx (look for the "Standard Numeric Format Strings" and "Custom Numeric Format Strings" links in that page).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you have been a great help and thanks for your patients. Its all now working perfectly!

Comment: I just added an answer with what was useful for you, so you can mark your question as answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store that value in any cell of the grid like this:

```
salecompgridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = ((December2014DailySales - December2013DailySales) / December2013DailySales * 100).ToString();
```

Just use the appropriate row and cell indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a row manually, and set the empty cells as "" and the non-empty cells with pre-calculated values. Hope it helps.